# For which $m$ is this sum of roots of unity $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, exponential-sum

A professor at my university gave me the following problem:

> For what real values of $m$ do we have
>   $$L=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Ne^{2\pi ik^3m}=0$$

If $m$ is rational, expressed as $\frac{a}{b}$, then let

$$\sum_{k=1}^be^{\frac{2a\pi ik^3}{b}}=c$$

Then we have that $L$ is equal to $\frac{c}{b}$, so that $L=0$ if and only if $c=0$.  However, I don't find it an easy problem to determine what rational numbers give $c=0$.  And I'm really unsure how to solve the problem for irrational $m$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tell your teacher that you only have the solution(s) for when there's an extra $\dfrac1{N^3}$ in the exponent. :-)

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: @Alizter: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Notice the "i" in the exponent. This makes it a sum of complex terms. The magic words you want to search on are "cubic exponential sums".

Comment: Care Bear pointed out that [Weyl's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) may be useful. It may be able to give you an asymptotic way to derrive $m$.